# How to insert an image into a nvarchar(max) in SQL server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I'm following an MVC 5 tutorial: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/dashboard-application-with-asp-net-mvc-5-and-jquery/

where the Author has a code-first migration that creates a table (among others) that has a CustomerImage column that becomes a nvarchar(max) in SQL server. He does not "seed" it nor shows how he populated the table. His demo app shows the images just fine.

I populate my version of his table using a SQL insert as such:

```
  INSERT [dbo].[Customer]
  (
    CustomerName
    ,CustomerEmail
    ,CustomerPhone
    ,CustomerCountry
    ,CustomerImage
 )
 VALUES
 (
   'Person 1'
   ,'Person1@hotmail.com'  
   ,'(203) 111-1111'
   ,'USA'
   ,(SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'C:\First\Images\Person1.jpg', 
    SINGLE_BLOB) as CustImage) 
 )
```

but my images do not appear in my partial view.

Is my insert incorrect?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: In this sample, the database column does not contain an actual image, but only the filename of an image file in the /images/customers subfolder of the web application. For example: "tarik.png"

Comment: Nailed it...thanks!

Comment: But by just supplying the image file name, how does it know its location - the path?

Comment: @NineBerry it is not true. `SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'C:\First\Images\Person1.jpg', 
    SINGLE_BLOB)` produces `varbinary(max)` data. The column in OP contains this image which is cast as `nvarchar(max)`

Comment: @user3020047  it's supplied in the view template. Look at customerslist.cshtml, which contains: `'<img class="rounded img-thumbnail" style="width:60px; height:58px;" src="/Images/Customers/' + data + '"/>'`

Comment: @AlexKudryashev I was explaining what the tutorial expects in the column

Comment: @NineBerry...I see it in the view template...thanks.

Comment: @NineBerry...1 more :)...how about the Product inage?
 I don't see a path. Here in the GetProductByCategory.cshtml, there is an helper method. No path though. @Html.ProductImage(product.ProductType, product.ProductImage, "300px", "165px")

Comment: In your case you should copy images to a folder (`<site-root>\image\customers`) and insert *file names* into `CustomerImage` column, not binary as you do.

Comment: @Alex Kudryashev...actually per NineBerry,,that is what the author is doing and I was doing it incorrectly.

Comment: @NIneBerry..without being too needy...I have another question that I posted titled: ASP.Net MVC and using Linq to Sql. Wondering if you can be of help on that 1 too...:)

Comment: @user3020047 you have the source for the Html.ProductImage function. You will see that it also builds the file path from the product category and the image filename of the product.